# SoundCloud web API user_favorite bug?

Tags: json, sdk, soundcloud, endpoint

When I hit the `me/activities/tracks/affiliated` web endpoint, it looks like the `user_favorite` flag doesn't appear for each of the returned items (contrary to every other endpoint that returns tracks).  Is this a known issue?

It be huge to have this addressed!  If it's intentional for that endpoint, then maybe provide an param for the endpoint to get this field because it's critical info for us!  Otherwise, when we display the user's stream items, theres not way to display an indicator if a track is liked without doing a query for each item, yikes!

If it matters, SoundCloud, we think you'll be VERY pleased with what we're making and will want to work with us on this one!  :)

Thanks!